# Asp.net page not working for user with chinese language settings

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a user who is chinese and apparently has some chinese settings on their windows computer.  When they attempt to access my website they are getting a server error with the event viewer simply calling it an unhandled exception.  I can't figure out how or what is going on and so far it's managed to avoid all of my try catch blocks.

Is there any basic tips I can do when handling potential incoming Chinese characters?

Comment: You need to find the exact error details.

Comment: Check the stack trace.

Comment: I'm confused how my try catch is being dodged.  The warning in the event viewer pointed me at a page, where I wrapped the page_load in a try catch.  Can the other sub routines in that page cause an event without triggering that try catch, considering all of them would of been called within page load?

Comment: We can't tell what you're doing wrong unless you show us the relevant code.